# C# WinForms Try Catch Inside a class

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I am using a service reference which connects to internet and I want to show message in a message box if ever the connection fails. How will I call message box in the member function of the class which has void return type? This is the member function of the class:

```
 public void ReverseGeocodePoint()
    {
        try{
        string results = "";
        string key = "abc";
        ReverseGeocodeRequest reverseGeocodeRequest = new ReverseGeocodeRequest();

        // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
        reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();
        reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

        // Set the point to use to find a matching address
        GeocodeService.Location point = new GeocodeService.Location();
        point.Latitude = latitude;
        point.Longitude = longitude;

        reverseGeocodeRequest.Location = point;

        // Make the reverse geocode request
        GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
        //This will connect to the server
        GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.ReverseGeocode(reverseGeocodeRequest);

        if (geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0)
            results = geocodeResponse.Results[0].DisplayName;
        else
            results = "No Results found";

        address = results;
    }} catch{ //here I want to show a msgbox but the problem is, this is not the form class}
```

Comment: Posting code would help in understanding your problem better.

Comment: You need to show us your code. Both what you have that works and what you have tried to write that doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't catch the exception in that class if there's nothing you can do about it there. Just let it bubble up and catch it where you *can* do something about it:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var sc = new ServiceClass();
            sc.ReverseGeocodePoint();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In `ReverseGeocodePoint()`, remove the `try/catch` statements.